# symfony2 hierarchical ACL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, acl

I've got the following problem:

Most of my entities are saved with a link to a tree structure with the [doctrine tree extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions). I started to implement the acl system but soon realised that it would't completely fit.

Small fictional example to make this clear:

- Sports group

  - Tennis group
  - Basketball group
  - Swimming group

News items can be added to these different groups. Now with the symfony acl i can grant rights to all or individual news entities. I would like to be able to grant rights to the entities in specific groups to one user.

Should i drop the use of the acl system and write my own or is there another way to fix this?